Anchor build: Error - Large stack variables
I am still getting these errors upon Anchor build despite others claiming it has been solved by simply upgrading to solana-cli versions 18.2.0 and higher.
Error: Function _ZN112_$LT$solana_program..instruction..InstructionError$u20$as$u20$solana_frozen_abi..abi_example..AbiEnumVisitor$GT$13visit_for_abi17hf6d5ed38e659ed87E Stack offset of 4608 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 512 bytes, please minimize large stack variables

Error: Function _ZN147_$LT$lending..instructions..create_loan..CreateLoan$u20$as$u20$anchor_lang..Accounts$LT$lending..instructions..create_loan..CreateLoanBumps$GT$$GT$12try_accounts17h3b0541fc6820fe84E Stack offset of 4120 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 24 bytes, please minimize large stack variables

Error: Function _ZN147_$LT$lending..instructions..obtain_loan..ObtainLoan$u20$as$u20$anchor_lang..Accounts$LT$lending..instructions..obtain_loan..ObtainLoanBumps$GT$$GT$12try_accounts17h3772087e39923fa3E Stack offset of 4536 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 440 bytes, please minimize large stack variables

However, when I downgrade back to solana-cli version 1.16.25, the errors go away. But then my problem lies in deploying the program to mainnet, hence why I wish to upgrade in the first place.

The problem is associated with the solana-program crate. Explicitly setting it to 1.18.2 solved it for me.
 cargo update -p solana-program@<SOLANA_PROGRAM_VERSION> --precise 1.18.2

Replace <SOLANA_PROGRAM_VERSION> with the version your project is using.
you'll need to search for the solana-program that your program is using in the Cargo.lock file or use cargo tree
cargo tree | grep solana-program


Thanks. I have tried to update as you said, but unfortunately I have dependencies which are locked to versions of solana-program < 1.18.0.
I'll come back to this after going through the crate inter-dependency nightmare with an update.
